# Translate text and <i>-tag inside an <a>-tag with CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, translate-animation

So I have the following situation for a button I am making:

```
<a href="#" class="button"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i> Previous</a>
```

which can be seen fully on https://jsfiddle.net/pre3xzL5/ (`<i>`-tag from Font Awesome).

Basically I want the text inside the button to be centered from the beginning (it isn't now), and then when I hover the arrow (`<i>`-tag) appears and comes from the middle to the left, and then the next should also go from the middle (centered as it should be) at moved a bit to the right. However, now, the next is starting at the place where it should be when hovered. It makes sense since the `<i>`-tag is taking up space, but that's the question: Can I correct this ?

I have done it using margins instead. But I've read that using margins for transitions and such is bad practice, and not good for performance - hence the try with translate.

Answer (score 0):

These two transition statements are the only ones you need, set initially on the relevant elements. The position absolute changed to position relative on hover gets you the effect you want.

```
.button 
{
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;

    i  
    {
        position:absolute;
        transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }
}

.button:hover 
{
   i 
   {
      position:relative;
   }
}
```

html:

```
<a href="#" class="button"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i> Previous</a>
```

scss:

```
.button {
background: red;
padding: 20px 20px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-radius: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
justify-self: center;
display: inline-block;
width: 140px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
border: 1px red solid;

i {
   position:absolute;
   opacity: 0.0;
   transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
   transform: translateX(.5em);
  }
}  

.button:hover {
    background: red;
  border: 1px black solid;

  i {
    position:relative;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1.0;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pre3xzL5/1/

Comment: Since you use SCSS, what about using `&:hover`?

Comment: In principle this almost works. However, as the arrow, i.e. sliding from the middle to the left, the text should slide from the center position and the a bit to the right as well. Now it just jumps with no smooth transition.

Comment: it's smoothed out a bit, that is up to you to twiddle with the transition to your heart's content @DenverDang wrapping the word in a span would help <a href="#" class="button"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span>Previous</span></a>